# Is there a heap class in C++ that supports changing the priority of elements other than the head?

Tags: c++, stl, boost, heap, priority-queue

I have a priority queue of events, but sometimes the event priorities change, so I'd like to maintain iterators from the event requesters into the heap.  If the priority changes, I'd like the heap to be adjusted in log(n) time.  I will always have exactly one iterator pointing to each element in the heap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm happy to report that Boost has now added a [Boost.Heap library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/heap.html) with some [stellar data structures](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/heap/data_structures.html).

The advantage of this is that Fibonacci heaps support changing priority in constant amortized time.

Unfortunately, all of the mutable heaps are node-based (in other words, they have extra indirection as suggested by @wilx).  @Feruccio's answer of Boost's “mutable heaps” has code that allows one to write vector-based mutable heaps if you're willing to have pointers to handles contained in your value type.

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at Boost's [mutable heaps](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/boost/pending/mutable_heap.hpp).

Comment: Thanks, if I end up having to roll my own, I'll use that snippet to start.

Comment: ended up going with this solution

Comment: @NeilG Have you tried to simply use std::map? Keys a priorities, values are vectors of events with same priority. An event needs to only store its position in the bucket. This is what I am using now and I am curious whether the solution suggested here is (much) faster...

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Lowering the priority in a `map` is O(log(n)).  If you use the Fibonacci heap, it will be O(1) amortized time.

Comment: @NeilG Lower complexity does not always translate into actual gains of speed. Also, I thought you went with `D-ary` mutable heaps, which are based on `vector` instead of nodes on free store. I believe that using integer arithmetic and contiguous memory should be much faster than using indirect access. Did you try this option?

Comment: @alwayslearning `map` cannot use contiguous memory.  It must be implemented as a tree in order to meet its complexity promises.  I think it's pretty clear that a tree will perform worse than a heap for implementing a priority queue.

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like you need more indirection. Store pointer to the events in the priority queue instead. When priority of some element of the queue changes, remove it and reinsert.

Answer (score 0):

A warning here is that you end up with unstable event sorting, i.e. ordering of the events with the same priority is undefined (read 'they will be reordered'.)

Comment: You can remove an arbitrary element from a heap in log(n) time.